# Google Apps Script - Google Analytics API - Return undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-docs-api

I'm running a script via Google Apps Script to grab data for a website via google analytics api.

The process is running fine and i can't change it to another script language.

For some URLs the returning result via the API is "undefined" which means for me it is like zero (because for other URLs when there is "undefined" i just got no traffic for this URL in a given time frame).

But for these URLs the traffic is not zero when i use the the web interface of google analytics.

**For some URLs it means:**

API Query: "undefined"
WEB Interface : 23243 (example)

The API query is perfectly working for most of the URLs in the list i have.

Only for some in randomly order they are not working.

Can you help me to find possible reason for that? I thought about some things like:

> These URL have different embedding of Analytics?
>
> These URLs have different tableID (i don't think it's possible because for the WEB Interface i use same tableID)

The "Date-Set-Up" (Timeframe) for these URLs is valid.

The "metric" and "option" is working for the URLs before and after in the list.

The only thing changed is the pagepath.

These pagepaths work perfectly in the Web Interface so there is no misspelling.

I don't know if these things make sense. Any hint could be helpful.